# Cases where the symmetry property of equality doesn't hold

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have seen proofs for the symmetry property of equality that go something along the lines of:

$a=b$ (premise)

$a=a$ (axiom of reflexivity) : it is $P(a/x)$, with $x=a$ as $P$

$a=b\implies(a=a\implies b=a)$ (axiom of substitution) : where $b=a$ is $P(b/x)$, with $x=a$ as $P$

$b=a$

I do have some confusions with this proof and am unsure I wrote it down correctly, but that's irrelevant to the question. My question lies in what set $a$ and $b$ are defined to be in. It's almost always undefined when I've seen the proof, and if it is defined it's done so for the reals, although I'm sure this applies to complex numbers as well, for example. So, for what mathematical objects is this proof true for? Why? And, my true question: If it's not defined for all objects, for which ones is it not and why? Can you give an example?

Comment: The usual axioms for equality a *reflexivity* and *substitution*; from them, *symmetry* follows. That's all

Comment: Equality has nothing to do with some containing set. The concept is if $a = b$, then $a$ and $b$ are two variables that have been assigned the same object as value. I.e., we have only one object, but we've given it two names. What set that object happens to be in doesn't change this,

Comment: @PaulSinclair that makes so much more sense, I wish that was more explicitly stated to me when reading about it